# Enable Open Link in New Tab with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a table with clickable rows that upon clicking will redirect to another page. I'm accomplishing this right now with Javascript. However if you right click there's no option to "Open Link in New Tab" presumably because the browser only does this for links? Is there a way to enable this behavior?

Basically I want table rows to act like anchor tags.

Comment: Why not add links to the cells? Alternative is to hook into the oncontextmenu

Comment: You can't make an entire row a link since the row parent must be a *tbody*, *thead* or *tfoot* element. The link must be inside a cell.

Comment: RobG is correct. I guess I could just make a link per cell but was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @jcmoney—elegance is in the eye of the beholder.:-) Making an entire row a link might make users nervous about clicking on the table, whereas if links are clearly identifiable, users can be confident of what will happen when they click wherever. It's all about least surprise—unless you're developing a game of course.:-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the link in each cell? I had a similar problem, when I was trying to make a whole row like a link, I used a link in each data cell:

```
<td><a class="mylink" href="URL" target="_blank">...</a></td>
...
<style>mylink {display:block; text-decoration:none; color:black;}</style>
```

This [target](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET.html) attribute will work even if JS is disabled.

Comment: My question is not how to make a link open in a new tab. Rather it's to have the option show up when you right-click on a table row.

Answer (score 1):

Here
http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/v5JrS/
the fiddle does not position the menu but the script does - tested in Fx5 on Mac:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#menu { display:none; position:absolute;border:1px solid red; background-color:grey }
#menuLink { text-decoration:none }
tr { border:1px solid black}
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function() {

  var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (var i=0,n=trs.length;i<n;i++) {
    trs[i].oncontextmenu=function(e) {
      document.getElementById("menuLink").href=this.cells[0].innerHTML;
      var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
      menu.style.left=(e)?e.pageX:event.clientX;
      menu.style.top=(e)?e.pageY:event.clientY;
      menu.style.display="block";
      return false;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("menuLink").onclick=function() {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.display="none";
    // the following is not really needed since the target works
    // fine on its own
//    var w=window.open(this.href,this.target);
//    return w?false:true;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>http://www.bing.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="menu"><a id="menuLink" target="_blank" href="">Open in new window/tab</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to enable this behavior easily to work on all browsers. What you have to do is manually update the `href` of your links to point to whatever page you want the user to go to. Note that this required use of anchor (`<a>`) tags, which may be difficult to do with table cells. Perhaps you can fill the cells with some sort of invisible image or play with CSS.

Look at http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/10629.htm - the fourth post.